# How to analyze thread dump for a Java server process in Unix

Tags: java, unix

I took the thread dump by running below command in my Unix machine:

```
kill -3 <process-id>
```

The thread dump is generated in log file, but how to analyze the data to know what went wrong with my server.

Comment: While not an unreasonable question per se, it is extremely open-ended.

Answer (score 0):

Start from Blocked thread and Thread waiting for Monitor.
If there is any Deadlock it will be printed at the end of the Log.
See if there is any condition where threads are fighting for resources and because of that deadlock is happening.
You have to do it by yourself. Do some research and analyze the Dump. It will take time but you can learn it.